# How can I know when the user hits home button on HoloLens 2 hand menu?

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, hololens

I am developing an XR app for the HoloLens2 and I need to know when the home button is pressed after opening the hand menu after pressing Windows button. Is there any way to get notified when home button was pressed or user wants to quit the application like that?

Comment: afaik not really ... I think you can only react in [`OnApplicationFocus`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationFocus.html) .. see [`OnApplicationQuit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationQuit.html) -> `On Windows Store Apps [which HoloLens2 is] and Windows Phone 8.1 there is no application quit event. Use the OnApplicationFocus event when focusStatus equals false.` .. closing apps on HoloLens basically equals killing them hard via TaskManager so there is no real reliable way of doing tasks based on this :/

Comment: Can look for the Suspend event for HoloLens to catch when the application pauses.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommend using the suspend events:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/

Example:

```
Application.Current.Suspending += OnSuspending;


private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
    var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
    // Save application state and stop any background activity
    deferral.Complete();
}
```